# How to share the screen in a multiplayer game?

Tags: java, javafx, rmi

I made a game in java all the GUI and key events etc are done using javafx.
The game is `Battle City` http://nintendo8.com/game/245/battle_city/

Now I have made it multiplayer using RMI.(client and server)
The other player movement etc is fine.

I am now stuck as to how I can share the screen between client and the server.

I have thought of serializing the root node and all the objects in it and sending it over to client in a while loop, but is this doable? Will it work?

And is there any better option?